# How can I GL_SELECT from a gluPerspective-transformed scene?

Tags: opengl, transformation, picking

I'm using JOGL to access OpenGL-methods on an old OpenGL version, because of school.

I have written a method which is called before any objects are drawn. This method shows which object is picked.

Before I call my "picking" method, I draw a camera. This is where the problems begin: I can't click precisely on the objects, because they don't know they are transformed by the camera.  I have tried to leave the projection matrix unchanged, but this leads to other problems...

I first draw the camera, then do picking, then draw the objects to screen.

What am I missing?

---

My camera:

```
public void draw(GL2 gl) {
    GLU glu = GLU.createGLU(gl);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    glu.gluPerspective(viewingAngle, whRatio, 1, 1000);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    glu.gluLookAt(xPos, yPos, distance, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

My picking method:

```
private void picking(GL2 gl) {
    if (currentClickPoint != null) {
        int buffSize = 512;
        int[] select = new int[buffSize];
        int viewport[] = new int[4];
        IntBuffer selectBuffer = newDirectIntBuffer(buffSize);

        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);

        gl.glSelectBuffer(buffSize, selectBuffer);
        //gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glRenderMode(GL2.GL_SELECT);
        gl.glInitNames();
        //gl.glPushName(-1);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        glut.gluPickMatrix((double) currentClickPoint[0],
                (double) (viewport[3] - currentClickPoint[1]),
                10.0, 10.0, viewport, 0);

        //gl.glOrtho(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0, -0.5, 2.5);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        drawObjects(gl, GL2.GL_SELECT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glFlush();


        selectBuffer.get(select);

        interpretClicks(select, gl.glRenderMode(GL2.GL_RENDER));

        resetClickPoint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the `gluPickMatrix` docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPickMatrix.xml), this function is designed to be used in tandem with your normal projection matrix.  In other words, it shouldn't *replace* the normal projection matrix as your code does, but be combined with it.

The docs suggest using the following sequence of calls to set up the picking matrix:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
glut.gluPickMatrix(...);
glu.gluPerspective(...);
```

The `gluPerspective` call would have the same arguments as in your normal camera setup.  The modelview matrix should also remain the same as in the normal camera setup.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me.
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glLoadIdentity();
glut.gluPickMatrix(..)
glut.gluPerspective(/*cam setup */
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
//draw my objects
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glFlush();

/* get buffer and interpret clicks */
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glPopMatrix();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);